# How to zip multiple RDDs in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

In spark there is `zipPartitions` to merge multiple RDDs into one. However, there is no such method available with pyspark RDD. If I use `zip` multiple times then I create one new dataframe per rdd that I combined, which is not what I want.

How can one zip multiple RDDs into one in pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. The introduction of `zipPartitions` in PySpark was [proposed in 2016](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/10550), but as you can read among comments, they never managed to find a good compromise between performances and solution complexity. The issue is now closed but I do not think it will be reopened in the near future. [This](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejegonzal/pyspark/_modules/pyspark/rdd.html) is the solution proposed by Joseph E. Gonzalez.

---

The quickest way to use that API is to write it yourself (performances will not be that good of course). A very naive `zipPartitions` implementation is:

```
def zipPartitions(rdd1, rdd2, func):
    rdd1_numPartitions = rdd1.getNumPartitions()
    rdd2_numPartitions = rdd2.getNumPartitions()
    assert rdd1_numPartitions == rdd2_numPartitions, "rdd1 and rdd2 must have the same number of partitions"
    
    paired_rdd1 = rdd1.mapPartitionsWithIndex(lambda index, it: ((index, list(it)),))
    paired_rdd2 = rdd2.mapPartitionsWithIndex(lambda index, it: ((index, list(it)),))
    
    zipped_rdds = paired_rdd1.join(paired_rdd2, numPartitions=rdd1_numPartitions)\
        .flatMap(lambda x: func(x[1][0], x[1][1]))
    
    return zipped_rdds
```

You can test it with:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize(range(30), 3)
rdd2 = sc.parallelize(range(50), 3)

zipPartitions(rdd1, rdd2, lambda it1, it2: itertools.zip_longest(it1, it2))\
    .glom().collect()
```

Arguments are easy to understand, they are, in order, the first rdd, the second rdd and a function accepting 2 partition iterators, one for each rdd.
With the `assert rdd1_numPartitions == rdd2_numPartitions` I make sure both rdd have the same number of partitions, that is a precondition for the Scala version too.
Then I use `mapPartitionsWithIndex` on both rdds to transform, for example, an rdd with two partitions, from:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

To

```
[(0, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), (1, [5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
```

---

**Note**: the conversion from `it` to `list(it)` is unfortunately necessary because in most of the python implementations you cannot pickle generators, and the `it` parameter is a generator. There is an exception that allows you to convert `it` into a list, a case that pyspark handles with a [very clever optimization](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/context.html#SparkContext.parallelize), I am talking about an rdd created from a `range()`. In fact, considering the previous example,

```
range(10)
```

becomes

```
[(0, range(0, 5)), (1, range(5, 10))]
```

---

Next I can `join` the two new rdds on the partition index. `numPartitions` can be easily predicted because we have previously asserted that both rdd must have the same number of partitions, so they are in a 1-to-1 relationship. Finally, I can apply the passed function and flatten the list of partition results.